# Calculate value of a real number, considering "n" as a natural number

Tags: complex-numbers, real-numbers

How could I calculate the value of the real number:

$$
(1 +i \sqrt{3})^n  + (1 - i \sqrt{3})^n
$$

...considering $n$ as a natural number and $i$ as the imaginary unit.

Comment: Does $$\left(\frac{1+i\sqrt{3}}{2}\right)^n$$ look somewhat familiar?

Comment: @DanielFischer I can't understand it, sorry I am starting now with complex numbers... Why did you divide the expression by two?

Comment: Because, as mentioned in two answers, $\frac{1+i\sqrt{3}}{2}$ is a root of unity (specifically, a primitive sixth root of unity).

Comment: Ah, ok! And how do you realize of that?

Answer (score 1):

Hint: 
$$
\bar{z}^n = \overline{z^n} \quad z + \bar{z} = 2 \mbox{Re}(z)
$$

Comment: Thanks I know it, but I don't remember how can I eliminate both exponents

Comment: @AlbertoFernández : $$z^n+\overline z^n=z^n+\overline{z^n}\;$$ This is just what the answerer wrote, and it even is true.

Comment: @Timbuc so can i put: $(1 + i*\sqrt{3})^{-n} + (1+i*\sqrt{3})^n$ ?

Comment: No @AlbertoFernández, of course not. Where do you get that from?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** We are looking at
$$2^n\left(\left(\frac{1+\sqrt{3}i}{2}\right)^n+\left(\frac{1-\sqrt{3}i}{2}\right)^n\right).$$
Inside we have sixth roots of unity, which cycle nicely.

**Remark:** I prefer to work with the complex exponential, but one could use  trigonometric.  Note that
$$1+\sqrt{3}\,i=2(\cos\theta+i\sin\theta),$$
where $\theta=\frac{\pi}{3}$. Taking the $n$-th power, and using the de Moivre formula, we get
$$(1+\sqrt{3}\,i)^n=2^n(\cos n\theta+i\sin n\theta).$$
Similarly, 
$$(1-\sqrt{3}\,i)^n=2^n(\cos n\theta-i\sin n\theta).$$
Add.

Comment: Thank you, and how do you realize that this numbers were sixth roots of unity? And why do you multiply by $2^n$ the expression?

Comment: You have probably seen the close relatives $(-1+\pm\sqrt{3}i/2)$. It is mostly a matter of having see them before. The division by $2$ (which produces the $2^n$ in front) is to make things easier to recognize. Now that we have the displayed formula, the inside only depends on the remainder when $n$ is divided by $6$. So there are at most $6$ computations to make. And not really $6$, there is further symmetry.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:
$$
\bigg({\frac{1 \pm i \sqrt{3}}2}\bigg)^3 = -1
$$